Access command line arguments as list or dictionary, using e.g. level=args.logging
I have a Python command line program that receives arguments from the command line. It uses code as follows:
import argparse
...
...
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
        description='Translate file ')
                    
    parser.add_argument('input', type=str,
                        help='Input file to translate)
    parser.add_argument('output', type=str, help='Generated translated file.')
    parser.add_argument('--logging', default=40, type=int,
                        help='NOTSET - 0, DEBUG - 10, INFO - 20, WARNING - 30, ERROR - 40, CRITICAL - 50')
...
...
args = parser.parse_args()

It then accesse the arguments using the following syntax, e.g.:
level=args.logging

What I would like to do is supply the arguments as a list or as a dictionary (whatever is most appropriate) because they mostly never change, but retain the ability to access the arguments using the above syntax so I don't have to change the rest of the program. Is it possible and how?
Thank you
I tried to find a solution in this forum as well as ask some of the AI bots but I could not find a satisfactory answer, that would allow me not to change the rest of the program.

Did you try a nargs='+'?

Thank you @hpaulj, The short answer is no, i didn't know nargs existed! The long answer is I posted this question because I hoped to receive an answer that I could use immediately, without having to learn how to answer it myself.
